# Unresolvable variable when trying to convert a double to a String

Tags: java, variables, queue, calculator

Before this I wrote a method for the shunting yard algorithm, here I want to create a method so that I can evaluate the postfix expression. I will call this calculate method so that I can perform it on the postfix queue.

```
public String calculate(Queue post, Stack polish) {
```

i will dequeue my queue and seperate into individual tokens to be read

```
    String token = post.Dequeue();
```

while there is a token to be read

```
    while(!(token==null)) {
        if(isOperator(token)) {
            double operand_2 = Double.parseDouble(polish.pop());
            double operand_1 = Double.parseDouble(polish.pop());
            if(token.contains("+")) {
                double result = operand_2 + operand_1;
            }
            else if(token.contains("-")) {
                double convert = operand_2 - operand_1;
            }
            else if(token.contains("/")) {
                double convert = operand_2/operand_1;
            }
            else if(token.contains("*")) {
                double convert = operand_2/operand_1;
            }
```

when i try to convert "convert" to a String, it tells me that convert cannot be resolved as a variable

```
            String result = Double.toString(convert);
            polish.push(result);
        }
        else if(isNumeric(token)){
            polish.push(token);
        }
        String finalVal = polish.pop();
        return finalVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Plz don't forget to vote&accept

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope issue.  When you declare a variable, the declaration lasts up till the next `}` character, out of those whose matching `{` character has already passed.  Because you declare `convert` inside each `if` or `else if` block, the declaration lasts until the end of that block.

What you need to do is to declare `double convert;` before all the `if` and `else` statements, so that the declaration lasts up until the point where you need to use `convert`.

You may also want to give it an initial value, such as `double convert = 0;` to handle the case where the operator doesn't match any of the `if` and `else if` statements.  Otherwise, you might end up with a different compile error.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `convert` inside that scope. it's not declared as a variable, so you get that error.

**Change to:**

```
    double convert;
    while(!(token==null)) {
            if(isOperator(token)) {
                double operand_2 = Double.parseDouble(polish.pop());
                double operand_1 = Double.parseDouble(polish.pop());
                if(token.contains("+")) {
                    double result = operand_2 + operand_1;
                }
                else if(token.contains("-")) {
                    convert = operand_2 - operand_1;
                }
                else if(token.contains("/")) {
                    convert = operand_2/operand_1;
                }
                else if(token.contains("*")) {
                    convert = operand_2/operand_1;
                }
```